# How can I publish Twist messages to /gazebo node(amcl_demo.launch)

Tags: gazebo, rviz, turtlebot, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I'm runnning TurtleBot on rviz, and I want to publish Twist messages to the "/gazebo" node  in order to control robot's velocity.
I wrote a publisher as below but it didn't work. 
How can I solve this ploblem? Could you tell me please?

my code↓↓

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
def callback(data):
    pub=rospy.Publisher("/gazebo",Twist,queue_size=10)
    vel_msg=Twist()
    print(data.linear.x,data.angular.z)
    vel_msg.linear.x=0
    vel_msg.angular.z=0
    pub.publish(vel_msg)

def main():
    rospy.init_node("GetVelocity")
    sub=rospy.Subscriber("/mobile_base/commands/velocity",Twist,callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__== "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

rqt_graph Image↓↓(while running "amcl_demo.launch"&"rviz"&"turtlebot_world.launch"&"above code")
[rqt_graph](https://imgur.com/a/43dCkc1)(red arrow in this picture shows what  I want to do)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302535/how-can-i-publish-twist-messages-to-/gazebo-node(amcl_demo.launch)/) by [Reulix](https://answers.ros.org/users/35653/reulix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-09-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2018-09-06**:
can you post the whole rqt_graph?

**Comment by [Reulix](https://answers.ros.org/users/35653/reulix/) on 2018-09-06**:
Yes, sure. Here you are!
[all nodes](https://imgur.com/a/omztNXN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are few mistakes in your code :

- You shouldn't initialize the publisher inside the callback it can create errors. Initialize it in the main function.
- You don't have to subscribe to any topic if you only want to publish a speed command.
- You are trying to publish data on the topic "/gazebo" but it's actually the name of the gazebo node so it cannot work.
- Since you have a cmd_vel multiplexer you can publish data on the topic `/cmd_vel` OR `/mobile_base/commands/velocity`
- You should set `vel_msg.linear.x` to some value (1 for example) to directly see your robot moving (it will be easier for you to debug)

It should work fine with those change.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reulix](https://answers.ros.org/users/35653/reulix/) on 2018-09-06**:
Thank you for your quick reply!!
Yes, subscriber isn't needed for this purpose, but I just wanted to check how TurtleBot would move
Ok I'll try it！

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2018-09-06**:
as mentioned in answer, publish to `/mobile_base/commands/velocity`, gazebo is just subscribing to this topic so you shouldn't publish anything to gazebo.

**Comment by [Reulix](https://answers.ros.org/users/35653/reulix/) on 2018-09-06**:
I made a Publisher in main function, set it to publish Twist topics to `/mobile_base/commands velocity` as you said, and I finally found TurtleBot would move as desired speed!!! Thanks to you, I could solve the problem!

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-09-06**:
I'm glad it worked well ! You can mark the answer as correct if you have no more issue

**Comment by [Reulix](https://answers.ros.org/users/35653/reulix/) on 2018-09-06**:
I did it!